# Copy-Item from Powershell v2 server to Powershell v5 localhost via PSSession

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-5.0, copy-item

It works to send files to a remote server (PowerShell version 2) from a localhost (PowerShell version 5) via the *PSSession* functionality:

`$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName xxx -Credential xxx
Copy-Item -Path 'xxx' -Destination 'xxx' -ToSession $s`

But is it also working to do the other way round in a convenient way (getting files back from server to localhost), so to not install any additional software, update PowerShell or to make it with PSDrive?

Note: PS v2 server is only reachable via IP and in another domain as localhost with PS v5!

PS: I tried `Copy-Item -Path 'some external path' -Destination 'some internal path' -FromSession $s` but the answer was: Destination folder xxx does not exist

Thanks!

Comment: You can use drive shares.  `-Destination '\\servername\C$\Temp'`

Comment: Also if there's no DNS but only IP available for the remote server?

Comment: Then use the IP instead of servername, it works the same way

Comment: I created a PSDrive on my local sys: `New-PSDrive -name X -provider FileSystem -root 'C:\mytemp'` but when referencing to that by `Copy-Item -Path 'external path' -Destination '\\localhost\X$' -FromSession $s` it also gives me a "Destination folder not exists"

Comment: You're using psdrive wrong. Imagine it's an actual drive on your pc, like C:\.  Your root would be \\localhost\C$\mytemp and your destination would be X:\

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'll post an answer then for future googlers